# Visual Basic code ends prematurely

Tags: vba, excel

I am modifying a Visual Basic code to import CSV file into Excel. The code ends prematurely without doing what it should. Debugging shows that at line `ws.name = line` it just skips the rest of the code and jumps to `End Sub`. What is the problem here?

Here is the code:

```
Sub ImportData()

    readCSV ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output.txt", "vbTab"

End Sub

Private Sub readCSV(parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim locNumCols As Long
    Dim fso As Variant
    Dim ts As Variant
    Dim line As Variant
    Dim lineSplit As Variant

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    On Error GoTo error_open_file
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
    On Error GoTo unhandled_error

    i = 1
    j = 1
    locNumCols = 0
    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
        line = ts.ReadLine
        If InStr(line, "New Sheet ") <> 0 Then
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            With ThisWorkbook
                Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            End With
            ws.name = line
            ws.Activate
            i = 1
            j = j + locNumCols
            locNumCols = 0
        Else
            lineSplit = Split(line, parDelimiter)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Resize(1, UBound(lineSplit, 1)) = lineSplit
            If locNumCols < UBound(lineSplit, 1) Then
                locNumCols = UBound(lineSplit, 1)
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

    ts.Close

error_open_file:             'returns empty variant
unhandled_error:             'returns empty variant

End Sub
```

Comment: That would be caused by `On Error GoTo unhandled_error` and `line` not containing a valid worksheet name

Comment: The only plausible explanation for _it just skips the rest of the code and jumps to End Sub_ is that `On Error GoTo unhandled_error` has fired. Try commenting out `On Error GoTo unhandled_error` and see what happens

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks, I found out the problem, the string exceeds the sheet name length limit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text you just read into `Line` is not a valid Worksheet name, the the Error Handler will fire and jump you to the `unhandled_error:` label (actually, the *next* line will be highlighted in single step mode, that's why it appears to skip to the `End Sub`)

If you can't guarantee the validity of the source data, your code needs to handle the possibility of an error, something like this. (I leave it to you to decide *what* to do about the failure)

```
On Error Resume Next
    ws.Name = line
On Error GoTo unhandled_error
If ws.Name <> line Then
    ' That Failed.  What now?
Else
    ' Carry On

End If
```

Side note, as Tim mentioned there are issues with your `Split` logic.  `Split` returns a `0` based 1D array, so `UBound(lineSplit)` is 1 less than the number of parts `line` is split into.

`ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Resize(1, UBound(lineSplit, 1)) = lineSplit` will not paste the last value from `lineSplit`.  And you will get a runtime error if there were no delimiters in `line`

Comment: Let me test it out and fix it step by step. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I added these lines for printing out the error:

```
unhandled_error:

    Dim Msg
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
```

Turns out the string exceeds the sheet name length. Thanks to @chrisneilsen for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

```
readCSV ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output.txt", "vbTab"
```

should probably be

```
readCSV ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output.txt", vbTab
```

unless the data is delimited not by tabs but literally "vbTab" (though you said it was CSV so...)

That might trigger an error here:

```
lineSplit = Split(line, parDelimiter)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Resize(1, UBound(lineSplit, 1)) = lineSplit
```

if there's no delimiter then `lineSplit` has UBound of zero and you can't resize to zero columns...

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Then follow @chrisneilsen's suggestion and let us know what happens